# Simple way to express disjunction likes x==a || x==b || x==c ||

Tags: simplifying-expressions, logic

Is there a **simple, shorter** way to express `x==1||x==2||x==3...` ?

For example, suppose that there is a *roulette* having integers 1 to 10
1> assigin 10% for 1 to 8 each
2> assign 15% for 9, assign 5% for 10
3> play roulette 100 times, and organize the result

```
D1 = ProbabilityDistribution[
Piecewise[{{1/10, 
     x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7 || x == 8},
    {3/20, x == 9},
    {1/20, x == 10}}], {x, 1, 10, 1}]
    
RandomVariate[D1, 100] // Tally // Sort // TableForm
```

Above example is acceptable, but what if the roulette had 100 numbers and we want to assign 1% for   50 fixed integers of irregular pattern like 1,3,6,8,9,11,17,... ?

I tried

`MemberQ[Range[8],x]` : not working as expected, because x is not a number.
`Element[x, Range[8]]` : not working either

[image]

Comment: In this specific case, why not just do `1 <= x <= 8`?

Comment: Thank you but what if the roulette had 100 numbers and we want to assign 1% for 50 fixed integers of irregular pattern like 1,3,6,8,9,11,17..?

Comment: I just found a working solution `ReplacePart[x == # & /@ Range[8], 0 -> Or]`, but I think there is a more frequently used, intuitive way to do this.

Comment: You could do `Or @@ Thread[x == Range[8]]` instead, if you want to take that route.

Comment: Thank you! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: `AnyTrue[Range[8],x==#&]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not being an expert in the statistical functions, I'm not sure about this, but would something like this work?

```
d1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, .5} -> Range[10]]
```

I know that doesn't answer the question, but since your example was very specific to probability distributions, I jumped to the conclusion that that was your ultimate goal.

Did a quick test, and it looks reasonable to me, but again, I'm a bit out of my depth here:

```
RandomVariate[d1, 10000] // Tally // Sort
(* {{1, 1006}, {2, 983}, {3, 968}, {4, 1018}, {5, 957}, {6, 1065}, {7, 1034}, {8, 1016}, {9, 1475}, {10, 478}} *)
```

Comment: Evaluating `Normalize[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3/2, 1/2}, Total]` should reproduce the original list of probabilities by the OP, which are indeed the correct weights to use in `EmpiricalDistribution[]`.